# PrimeFaces TreeTable is not working

Tags: primefaces

I cant even get to work the [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTable.jsf) code at all. What is the type of the Document` in the JavaBean code? In the older version of the free User Guide there is a different type of implementation for this TreeTable component.

[image]

Which implementation is correct? Is the Showcase showing wrong code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Primefaces showcase displays an old version of the DocumentsController class.

I found a different one in the [Primefaces sources](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/prime-showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/examples/view/DocumentsController.java?r=2173) containing *selectedDocument* of type **TreeNode** and not **Document**.

You will find older versions of this class there as well for comparison.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the older version also. It either is not working. How it is running in the showcase i wonder :)

Comment: I think the source from the link is the most recent version. What does it mean not working? Please add some code / error messages.

Comment: if you can try the code from the showcase, it is causing an error. It comes some property not found messages for each p:column. Im going to use h:dataTable instead of this buggy TreeTable

Comment: @Selvin : Hi Selvin, Sorry for asking you after a very long time. Me too getting the same problem. To make it work, what I have to do ?

Comment: @ArunRaj Not a problem. I distinctly remember that I was not able to overcome this problem and finally I fell back using h:dataTable instead of treeTable. You could ask this question to Cagatay who is the owner of primefaces development. Not in SO, may be in one of his forums.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an error. The Document class is your bean you want to show in each row. It's your data model.
Every TreeNode contains variable "data" of type Object - you can put there just String or any POJO you want - in this case a (custom) Document class instances.

So, if you write your own JavaBean Abc